# How to edit Nexus welcome screen

Tags: nexus

I would like to display custom information on my Nexus server, e.g. on the Welcome Screen or in a header. Basically I would like to add useful information for my users, like a contact address specific to my organization in case of issues, or links to guidance documents.

Is there any way to do this?

Comment: The question was voluntarily broad because there were probably several ways of doing what I was asking, and I did not mind which. Also I had not enough knowledge, even after a Google search, to restrict the question better. I am glad I at least managed to get answers before you guys closed the topic! Also, you may want to consider that it is a pain in the ass to manage to get up to 15 rep to be able to upvote and upload images, which in turns leads to more activity and more precise questions. If you downvote the few questions I ask, I will get there even slower. Not very helpful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The branding plugin can be used to update the header image in the top left corner. There is a [demo of that you can watch](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mf6Qlym9m9w&index=13&list=PLGB2s-U5FSWN4G3EuBoAhVMBhlHktK2JG) on the Sonatype Youtube Channel. There is no plugin to customize the welcome screen. You would have to write your own plugin to do that.

Update: The branding plugin is part of Nexus Pro only in the Nexus 2 series. The Nexus 3 series introduces a feature to have a completely customizable header and footer.

Comment: It seems that you missed to specify that this plugin is available only in Nexus Pro and not in Nexus OSS.

Comment: Correct. I will update the answer.

Answer (score 1):

I have never used it but there is a branding plugin:

- http://books.sonatype.com/nexus-book/reference/nexus-branding.html.

Might only apply to Nexus Prodfessional, worth checking out